# how to access a specific part of an ArrayList from one class to another

Tags: java, eclipse, scope

```
package HW1;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Arrays {
public ArrayList  Case() {
    ArrayList <Case> cases = new ArrayList<Case>();
    Case c1 = new Case("Antec Twelve Hundred V3", 20.20, 8.39, 22.87, "ATX Full         Tower", 154.99);
    Case c3 = new Case("BitPhenix Phenom M Arctic", 9.80, 12.95, 14.69, "MicroATX Mini Tower", 89.99);
    Case c2 = new Case("Corsair 250D", 13.8, 10.9, 11.4, "MiniITX Tower", 99.9);


    cases.add(c1);
    cases.add(c2);
    cases.add(c3);

    for (int i = 0; i < cases.size(); i++ ) {
        System.out.println("Name: " + cases.get(i).getName() + "\n" + "Dimensions: " + cases.get(i).getLength() + "' x " + cases.get(i).getWidth() + "' x " + cases.get(i).getHeight() + "' " + "Type: " +cases.get(i).getType() + "\n" + "Price: $" + cases.get(i).getPrice()+ "\n");
    }
   return cases;
}

public ArrayList  Monitor() {
    ArrayList <Monitor> monitor = new ArrayList<Monitor>();
    Monitor m1 = new Monitor("Asus PB278Q", 27, 549.99);
    Monitor m2 = new Monitor("Dell U2412M", 24, 263.99);
    Monitor m3 = new Monitor("Samsung S22300H", 21.5, 139.99);

    monitor.add(m1);
    monitor.add(m2);
    monitor.add(m3);

    for (int i = 0; i < monitor.size(); i++ ) {
        System.out.println("Name: " + monitor.get(i).getName() + "\n" + "Size: " + monitor.get(i).getSize() + "' " + "\n" + "Price: $" + monitor.get(i).getPrice() + "\n");
    }

   return monitor;
}

public ArrayList  CPU() {
    ArrayList <CPU> cpu = new ArrayList<CPU>();
    CPU cpu1 = new CPU("AMDFX-8350", 4.0, 188.99);
    CPU cpu2 = new CPU("Intel Core i5-3570K", 3.4, 179.99);
    CPU cpu3 = new CPU("Intel Core i7-3770K", 3.5, 249.99);

    cpu.add(cpu1);
    cpu.add(cpu2);
    cpu.add(cpu3);

    for (int i = 0; i < cpu.size(); i++ ) {
        System.out.println("Name: " + cpu.get(i).getName() + "\n" + "Speed: " + cpu.get(i).getSpeed() + "GHz " + "\n" + "Price: $" + cpu.get(i).getPrice() + "\n");
    }
   return cpu;
}

public ArrayList  VideoCard() {
    ArrayList <VideoCard> videoCard = new ArrayList<VideoCard>();
    VideoCard vd1 = new VideoCard("Nvidia GeForce GTX 770", 2, 346.99);
    VideoCard vd2 = new VideoCard("Nvidia GeForce GTX 670", 2, 333.99);
    VideoCard vd3 = new VideoCard("AMD Radeon HD 7950", 3, 399.99);

    videoCard.add(vd1);
    videoCard.add(vd2);
    videoCard.add(vd3);

    for (int i = 0; i < videoCard.size(); i++ ) {
        System.out.println("Name: " + videoCard.get(i).getName() + "\n" + "Memory Size: " + videoCard.get(i).getMemorySize() + "GB " + "\n" + "Price: $" + videoCard.get(i).getPrice() + "\n");
    }
   return videoCard;
}

public ArrayList  HardDrive() {
    ArrayList <HardDrive> hardDrive = new ArrayList<HardDrive>();
    HardDrive hd1 = new HardDrive("Samsung MZ-7PD256BW", 256, 199.99);
    HardDrive hd2 = new HardDrive("Corsair CSSD-F240GBGT-BK", 240, 206.99);
    HardDrive hd3 = new HardDrive("Crucial CT128M4SSD1", 128, 199.95);

    hardDrive.add(hd1);
    hardDrive.add(hd2);
    hardDrive.add(hd3);

    for (int i = 0; i < hardDrive.size(); i++ ) {
        System.out.println("Name: " + hardDrive.get(i).getName() + "\n" + "Memory Size: " + hardDrive.get(i).getSize() + "GB " + "\n" + "Price: $" + hardDrive.get(i).getPrice()+ "\n");
    }
    return hardDrive;
}

public ArrayList  Memory() {
    ArrayList <Memory> memory = new ArrayList<Memory>();
    Memory me1 = new Memory("Corsair Vengeance", 8, 69.99);
    Memory me2 = new Memory("G.Skill Ares Series", 16, 149.99);
    Memory me3 = new Memory("Kingston Black Series", 8, 79.99);

    memory.add(me1);
    memory.add(me2);
    memory.add(me3);

    for (int i = 0; i < memory.size(); i++ ) {
        System.out.println("Name: " + memory.get(i).getName() + "\n" + "Memory Size: " + memory.get(i).getSize() + "GB " + "\n" + "Price: $" +   memory.get(i).getPrice()+"\n");
    }
    return memory;
}

 }
```

Let's say I want to access the price for `c3`. In the same method I can just print it     but I want to access the price for `c3` on a main method in another class. Here is the code. Let's say that from the menu, the user enters `1` and decides to buy the first option. I got it to print the options, but I don't know how to access the price for it.

```
package HW1;
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
public static void printMenu() 
{
    System.out.println("Menu");
    System.out.println("1: Choose a Case");
    System.out.println("2: Choose a Monitor");
    System.out.println("3: Choose a CPU");
    System.out.println("4: Choose a Video Card");
    System.out.println("5: Choose a Hard Drive");
    System.out.println("6: Choose a Memory");
    System.out.println("7: Delete Current Computer");
    System.out.println("8: Display Receipt");
    System.out.println("9: Quit program");
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    printMenu();
    System.out.println("please select and option");
    Arrays arrays = new Arrays();


      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice = in.nextInt();
        if (choice == 1) {
            ArrayList cases = arrays.Case();
            System.out.println(cases);
            System.out.println("please select a case");
            if (choice == 1) {
                System.out.println(c1.getPrice());
            }
        }


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you can get the `Cases` from the `array`s class...

```
ArrayList cases = arrays.Case();
```

Next, you need to find out which case the user is interested in...

```
int choice = -1;
do {

    System.out.println("please select a case");
    choice = in.nextInt();
    if (choice >= cases.size()) {
        System.out.println("Please select from 0-" + (cases.size() - 1));
    }

} while (choice < cases.size());
```

Then you need to simple access the specified item from the `ArrayList`

```
// Allow for a non-positive exit value...
if (choice >= 0) {
    // I know, blind cast, bad idea...keep reading...
    Case aCase = (Case)cases.get(choice);
    System.out.println(aCase.getPrice());
}
```

Take a closer look at [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) for more details.

**Suggestions**

Beware that there is already a class called `Arrays` in the libraries, it might be a good idea to rename it to remove confusion.

In order to prevent the need to cast the element from the `ArrayList`, you should be providing a generic return result, for example...

Instead of `public ArrayList  Case() {`, you should be using `public ArrayList<Case> Case() {`, this ensures that when you do `cases.get`, the compiler will expect a `Case` and means you can get away with doing something like `Case case = cases.get(choice);` which is much safer.

In Java it is recommended that Java method names start with a lowercase

```
public ArrayList<Case> case() {...
public ArrayList<Monitor> monitor() {...
```

It might also be appropriate to use `get` for methods that "get" stuff, for example...

```
public ArrayList<Case> getCases() {...
public ArrayList<Monitor> getMonitors() {...
```

Comment: ok i took some of your suggestions into account and change the Case() method to case1 since the compiler thinks its case. on the if statement that you provided i get 2 errors it say that Case can not be resolve to a variable and to delete case, also that case is an invalid expresion

Comment: What package does `Case` reside?  Did you import it?

Comment: i have other classes like Case, Monitor, etc just like the arrays and they just return the name and price of the item all the classes are in  the same package

Comment: i made a change to Case case = (Case)cases.get(choice);
    System.out.println(case.getPrice()); i change case to case1 and the error went away but i still cant get the right price after the options display

Comment: I'm such an idiot `case` is a reserved word :P, sorry.  Then I'd suggest there is something wrong with `Case`, but I don't have enough to go on